# Add transition to jQuery .html

Tags: jquery

How could I smoothly transition jQuery .html?

http://jsfiddle.net/uSmaU/1/

```
$( '.profile' ).click(function() {
$('#section1target').addClass( "show-details" );

    $('#section1target').html($(this).find(".details").html());
});

.show-details { display:block;background:#f6f6f6;padding:30px;margin:0 30px 20px 0;font-size:15px;line-height:25px;
    -webkit-transition: all 4s ease-out 1s;
    -moz-transition: all 4s ease-out 1s;
    -o-transition: all 4s ease-out 1s;
    transition: all 4s ease-out 1s;
 }
```

Not quite the effect I was going for.

Comment: Are we supposed to guess what kind of transition you are going for? Also, whoever close-voted duplicate -- the answers in the link don't really provide an answer to this question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/uSmaU/5/)

judging by your CSS you want a fade?

```
$( '.profile' ).click(function() {
    var that = this;
    $('#section1target').fadeTo(400,0,function(){
        $(this).html($('.details', that).html()).fadeTo(600,1);
    });
});
```

Here's [an example](http://jsfiddle.net/uSmaU/7/) with slide + fade:

```
$( '.profile' ).click(function() {
    var that = this;   
    var h = $('#section1target').height();
    $('#section1target').animate({height:'toggle', opacity:0},h?400:0, function(){
        $(this).html($('.details', that).html()).animate({height:'toggle', opacity:1});
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

This could be my smallest make up to existing code to achieve a fade in

```
$( '.profile' ).click(function() {
    $('#section1target').hide().html($('.details',this).html()).fadeIn();
});
```

Comment: as UI designers we should avoid 'jumpy' interfaces. Users should always be able to follow up with *sense* what happens to the page